# onInfoWindowClick Method not working in android

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I have create a app where showing my current location in maps.I want to show places in toast message under onInfoWindowClick method. But toast not working .Thanks in advance for help!

Here is my code :

```
public  class SearchProviderLocation extends Activity implements LocationListener,OnInfoWindowClickListener   {

class MyInfoWindowAdapter implements InfoWindowAdapter{

    private final View myContentsView;

    MyInfoWindowAdapter(){
        myContentsView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_contents, null);
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

        TextView tvTitle = ((TextView)myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.title));
        tvTitle.setText(marker.getTitle());
        TextView tvSnippet = ((TextView)myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.snippet));
        tvSnippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());

        return myContentsView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}


final int RQS_GooglePlayServices = 1;
TextView tvLocInfo;
GoogleMap map;
private LocationManager locationManager;
protected LocationListener locationListener;
protected Context context;
String provider;
double latitude;
protected double longitude; 
protected boolean gps_enabled,network_enabled;

private String val,val1;
private static final long MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1; // in Meters
private static final long MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 1000; // in Milliseconds

boolean isGPSEnabled ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_provider_location);


    try {

        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
           lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
               map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();

               map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new MyInfoWindowAdapter());

         }      

    catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    map.clear();

    Geocoder geo = new Geocoder(this.getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
  try {
        List<Address> addresses = geo.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);

        MarkerOptions mp = new MarkerOptions();

           mp.position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
           mp.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker));

           mp.snippet("Address:"+" "+" "+addresses.get(0).getFeatureName()+" "+addresses.get(0).getAdminArea()+" "+addresses.get(0).getLocality()+" "+addresses.get(0).getPostalCode()+""+addresses.get(0).getCountryCode());
           mp.title(addresses.get(0).getLocality()+", "+addresses.get(0).getCountryName());

           map.addMarker(mp);
           map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
            new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 14)); 
  } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());

    if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                "GooglePlayServicesAvailable", 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, RQS_GooglePlayServices);    
    }
}

public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
    tvLocInfo.setText("New marker added@" + point.toString());

    Marker newMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(point)
                                .snippet(point.toString()));
    newMarker.setTitle(newMarker.getId());

}
@Override
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker)
{
   marker.getTitle();
   final String ssid = marker.getTitle(); 

   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"You click @" + ssid,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {


}                   

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}}
```

Comment: Where you set `InfoWindowAdapter()` ?

Comment: Kindly go to this: [http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/customizing-infowindow-contents-in-google-map-android-api-v2-using-infowindowadapter/](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/customizing-infowindow-contents-in-google-map-android-api-v2-using-infowindowadapter/)

Comment: better to implement `onMarkerClick(.....)`

Comment: okay . Trying to include

Comment: @SimplePlan i add map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() this.But  not working.Can you help me in code. i am new in android

Comment: @Amitya post your new code.

Comment: @SimplePlan Pressing Ctrl+Shift+z ..wait please

Comment: I follow http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/01/create-custom-info-contents-for-by.html

Comment: Not yet .I modify the code above

Comment: remove `implements  OnInfoWindowClickListener` from your activity

Comment: and make sure you'll get values into `addresses`.

Comment: @SimplePlan Thanks. I have a query to you that . When i click in marker it shows total address. Can i implement on it ? Actually i want show address in toast messages . Is it possible ?

Comment: off course possible but doing it on Background

Comment: @SimplePlan I have done this previous day night . Many thanks for advice (y)

Comment: OMG! and you succeed! that's awesome

Comment: @Intellij Amiya  how you solved your problem.. i have a same problem.. toast not working in onInfoWindowClick

Comment: @SagarChavada check below accepted answer

Comment: its not working for me. thats why i m asking.

Comment: @SagarChavada facing same problem yet ?

Comment: its working now..

Comment: @SagarChavada how can you solved this .Post here as answer .

Comment: your accepted answer is right, actually i was clicking on marker, and after i realize its only work when click on infoWindow.

Comment: @SagarChavada indeed indeed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try Below Code:

```
map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener()
{
    @Override public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0) {
        final String ssid = arg0.getTitle(); 
        Toast.makeText(SearchProviderLocation.this,"You click @" + ssid,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Don't forget to add something like `googleMap.setOnInfoWindowLongClickListener(this)` in `onMapReady` :)